# How do I search a file using "less" for a value with a decimal point?

Tags: regular-expression, less

So I less my file:

```
less myFile.log
```

Then I try to search for a value:

```
/70.5
```

I've since learned less uses regex, so `.` is a wildcard. I've tried to escape it with no success.

Comment: How did you *"try to escape it with no success"* without using a backslash?

Comment: You answered your own question.  If I used a backslash I would have _succeeded_, wouldn't I have..?

Comment: Maybe I'll rephrase it slightly: What exactly did you type when you tried to *escape* the decimal with no success? Or did you only press slash to search, then typed `70.5`? Maybe there's a misunderstanding of "escape"?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can turn off regex mode by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> before typing the pattern:

> ```
>           ^R     Don't interpret regular expression metacharacters; that is,
>                  do a simple textual comparison.
> ```

Comment: Amazing trick, thanks for this!  Is it specific to less?

Comment: @xeon48 likely it is - at least, I don't think `more` supports it (although other pagers may provide something equivalent)

Comment: Thanks steel, I'll play around with it when I get a chance :)

Comment: @xeon48 : it seems specific to less, but there are some alternatives (`fgrep "something" file(s)`  : will look for the exact string "something" in the file(s), doing a car by car comparison and not as a regexp)

Answer (score 31):

```
/70\.5
```

will do the trick (inside `less`).

Comment: Alternatively: `/70[.]5`.

Answer (score 5):

## Two search expressions for numbers in `less`

```
/\.*[0-9]+\.*     # for numbers

/[0-9]*\.[0-9]+   # for numbers with a decimal part
```

### Regex to search for numbers (with or without a decimal)

This regex works in `less` but also in other cases where the same regex syntax is used.

```
\.*[0-9]+\.*
```

You start the search engine with `/`, so if you want to find decimal numbers, but avoid text with dots (like file.txt) or periods between sentences, I think the following string is rather good,

#### `/\.*[0-9]+\.*`

Test file

```
There are several ways to use a dot. Here are some examples:

- 'Period' finishing a sentence
- Short for current directory or 'source' command in linux shells
- Separator between the name and extension of a file
- Separator in between the integer part and decimal part of a number
- Separator in special numerical or litteral strings (for example IP adress)

The following regex expression is rather simple and can identify
- numbers
- numerial strings

\.*[0-9]+\.*

.bashrc
hello-0
170.5
text.txt
170
170.
.551
asdf 170.5 qwerty
192.168.1.1
file.000
file.001
```

[image]

### Regex to search for numbers with a decimal part

This regex works in `less` but also in other cases where the same regex syntax is used.

```
[0-9]*\.[0-9]+
```

The corresponding search command is

#### `/[0-9]*\.[0-9]+`

It will also find numerical strings (for example IP address), in general digits after a dot (including digits before the dot, if any).

Comment: Thanks for this, it will come in useful.  Though the lesson learned here is brush up on my regex :)

Comment: `[0-9]*\.[0-9]*` matches on a single `.`. `*` matches on **zero** or more.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Yes, I know, and I am busy trying to get around that without getting a complicated expression ...

Comment: `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?` or even `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` maybe?

Comment: @StephenKitt, I think your first expression finds the same 'candidates' as my first string `\.*[0-9]+\.*` in the current version of the answer. Your second string will exclude some of dots (which may be good or bad depending on what the user wants to see).

Comment: Not quite, `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?` only matches a single dot following one or more digits, and it extends the match to cover digits following the dot too.

Comment: @StephenKitt, `<<< '.123' grep -oE '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?'` prints `123`, and `.123` is common syntax in English speaking countries (in Sweden, we learn to write  `0,123`). I am afraid, that there is no regex, that is both finding numbers (including decimal point and decimals) but not other strings with digits and dots, and simple enough to be used for this purpose in `less`. But our regexes are useful anyway, and even if they are not exactly the same, they give similar and useful results (the same for many typical cases as seen by the high-lighted strings, sometimes different with `grep -o`).

Comment: I agree, there’s no great solution, as illustrated by the IP address in your example.